# Filter and limit on a python dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

Given:

```
obj = {}

obj['a'] = ['x', 'y', 'z']
obj['b'] = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'u', 't']
obj['c'] = ['x']
obj['d'] = ['y', 'u']
```

How do you select (e.g. print) the top 2 entries in this dictionary, sorted by the length of each list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the top 2 entries in this dictionary, sorted by the length of each
>   list

```
print(sorted(obj.values(), key=len)[:2])
```

The output:

```
[['x'], ['y', 'u']]
```